# Neo4j Check a Single Node for multiple Relationships and Return if either exists

Tags: inheritance, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to test if any 2 patterns exist on a single Node. IF both patterns are present I get a result BUT if ONLY 1 pattern is present I get no results. HOW do I write the query so that I get a result IF either one or both patterns exist?

[image]

(this is an example if BOTH patterns exist - Result is Returned)
MATCH (characteristic)<-[:HAS]-(thing {name:'ball'})<-[:IS_A*]-(decendent)-[r:HAS]->(characteristic)
MATCH (characteristic2)-[r2:HAS]->(thing2 {name:'ball'})<-[:IS_A*]-(decendent2)<-[:HAS]-(characteristic)
RETURN decendent, decendent2
Now imagine if I ONLY have the Bounce Relationship. The Query above will Return Nothing. It only Returns IF Both are True. How do I Match if either is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `OPTIONAL MATCH` https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/optional-match/

Your query can be re-writtten as,

```
MATCH (characteristic)<-[:HAS]-(thing {name:'ball'})<-[:IS_A*]-(decendent)-[r:HAS]->(characteristic)
OPTIONAL MATCH (characteristic2)-[r2:HAS]->(thing2 {name:'ball'})<-[:IS_A*]-(decendent2)<-[:HAS]-(characteristic)
RETURN decendent, decendent2
```

This will return results if either descendant is matched by the respective clauses

Comment: Also because I don't know what one MAY return as a result I think I want them both OPTIONAL MATCH

Comment: UPDATE the best query when trying to do something like this is to First MATCH your Node then use that as a variable throughout the OPTIONAL MATCHES.   

MATCH (thing {name: 'ball'}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[:HAS]-(thing)<-[:IS_A*]-(d)-[r:HAS]->(c) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (c2)-[r2:HAS]->(thing)<-[:IS_A*]-(d2)<-[:HAS]-(c2) 
RETURN d, d2